# TypeError: byte indices must be integers

Tags: python

I want to get the top artists from a specific country from the last fm API in JSON and save the name and url in the `name` and `url` variables. But it always appears "TypeError: byte indices must be integers". Do you know where is the issue?

Working example:

```
import requests

api_key = "xxx"     


for i in range(2,5):

    artists = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page='+str(i)+'&api_key='+api_key)
    for artist in artists:

        print(artist)

        #name = artist['topartists']['artist']['name']
        #url  = artist['topartists']['artist']['url']
```

Comment: You should probably REMOVE YOUR API KEY from the question. And get a new one after.

Comment: you should probably not be posting your api_key on public sites...

Comment: You need to access [`artists.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Comment: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page=1&api_key=3dc24ba195e232058d7a623a80be1f6e still works. Don't forget to have your API key revoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
response = requests.get(...)
data = response.json()
for artist in data["topartists"]["artist"]:
    name = artist["name"]
    # etc
```

Explanation: `requests.get()` returns a `response` object. Iterating over the response object is actually iterating over the raw textual response content, line by line. Since this content is actually json, you want to first decode it to Python (`response.json()` is mainly a shortcut for `json.loads(response.content)`). You then get a python dict with, in this case, a single key "topartists" which points to a list of "artist" dicts.

A couple hints:

First you may want to learn to use string formatting instead of string concatenation. This :

```
'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page='+str(i)+'&api_key='+api_key
```

is ugly and hardly readable. Using string formatting:

```
urltemplate = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page={page}&api_key={api_key}"
url = urltemplate.format(page=i, api_key=api_key)
```

but actually `requests` knows how to build a querystring from a dict, so you should really use this instead:

```
query = {
    "method": "geo.gettopartists", 
    "country":"spain", 
    "format":"json", 
    "api_key": api_key
    }

url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/"
for pagenum in range(x, y):
    query["page"] = pagenum
    response = requests.get(url, params=query)
    # etc
```

Then, you may also want to handle errors - there are quite a few things that can go wrong doing an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks. But now appears the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" on the " name = artist["name"]".

Comment: @OzzyW indeed, you actually need `data["topartists"]["artist"]`, my bad (fixed in the answer)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: @OzzyW glad it could help. And don't forget to revoke the apikey you posted and get a new one... (hopefully you didn't ask about credit card validation xD)

Comment: Lol, but it seems ok to share the lastfm apikey and also it seems that its not possible to reveoke it. You can create a new one but the previous continues active..