# Python TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, azure, function, python-requests, typeerror

Before I start, I understand there are a lot of posts using the same title; I will try to keep this post unique.

I am creating a Azure Function that makes an API call (*I have left out the dynamicOAuth for clarity*).

```
import json, requests    
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:       
        # api_headers = dynamicOAuth(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
        software_vulnerabilities_api = request_data(api_headers)    
        return func.HttpResponse(software_vulnerabilities_api, status_code=200)

def request_data(api_headers):
    svbm = requests.get("...", headers=api_headers) 
    body = svbm.content
        
    return body['value']
```

This is an example of the successful API response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.windowsDefenderATP.api.PublicAssetVulnerabilityDto)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21-_-CVE-2020-6494-_-microsoft-_-edge_chromium-based-_-81.0.416.77-_-",
            "cveId": "CVE-2020-6494",
            "machineId": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21",
            "fixingKbId": null,
            "productName": "edge_chromium-based",
            "productVendor": "microsoft",
            "productVersion": "81.0.416.77",
            "severity": "Low"
        },
        {
            "id": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283-_-CVE-2016-3348-_-microsoft-_-windows_server_2012_r2-_-6.3.9600.19728-_-3185911",
            "cveId": "CVE-2016-3348",
            "machineId": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283",
            "fixingKbId": "3185911",
            "productName": "windows_server_2012_r2",
            "productVendor": "microsoft",
            "productVersion": "6.3.9600.19728",
            "severity": "Low"
        }
    ]

}
```

I wish to access 'value' and return a list of nested objects as so:

```
value = [
        {
            "id": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21-_-CVE-2020-6494-_-microsoft-_-edge_chromium-based-_-81.0.416.77-_-",
            "cveId": "CVE-2020-6494",
            "machineId": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21",
            "fixingKbId": null,
            "productName": "edge_chromium-based",
            "productVendor": "microsoft",
            "productVersion": "81.0.416.77",
            "severity": "Low"
        },
        {
            "id": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283-_-CVE-2016-3348-_-microsoft-_-windows_server_2012_r2-_-6.3.9600.19728-_-3185911",
            "cveId": "CVE-2016-3348",
            "machineId": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283",
            "fixingKbId": "3185911",
            "productName": "windows_server_2012_r2",
            "productVendor": "microsoft",
            "productVersion": "6.3.9600.19728",
            "severity": "Low"
        }
    ]
```

I am experiencing difficulties with accessing value within the JSON object. I have tried making use of json.loads() to parse the response, but I keep getting the same TypeError:

```
Exception: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

From what I understand, the `return body` in `requests_data(api_headers)` would return the entire JSON object and from here, I should be able to make use of:

```
body['value']
```

To access the list of nested JSON objects.

I an wondering whether it's an issue with the `main()` function. Does `return func.HttpResponse()` only accept a particular value in its response? Or do I need to convert the response of the body to UTF-8 prior to processing the data in the body?

When I return `body`, I receive a JSON object. This is the only method for getting a response that doesn't error.

Any help is greatly appreciated. It's been a while since I've made use of Python opposed to JS.

If any further information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- In Python, each element in a list has its own position. An index is used to define this place. Integers are always used to define these indexes. A variable with the index value of a list element could be declared.
- When you try to retrieve a value or an index of a list using a string, Python throws a TypeError.
- If this variable has a string value instead of an integer value, you'll get an error that says "**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**."
- To avoid this mistake, make sure the variable is always assigned an integer value.

For more information refer these similar SO thread links.

[TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102398/typeerror-byte-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)
[TypeError: byte indices must be integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350672/typeerror-byte-indices-must-be-integers)
[TypeError byte indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639273/typeerror-byte-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)